# (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version )

Tags: php

```
SELECT categories_id, categories_name, parent_id, sort_order, date_added, is_active 
FROM ct_testing_menu_title 
where parent_id='0' 
where All Fields like '%local%' 
order by `sort_order` ASC 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Error:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where All Fields like '%local%' order by `sort_order` ASC LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: [take a moment to write a proper question please](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

`ALL` is a MySQL reserved word

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

that is used in sub-queries:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html

utilizing the following syntax:

```
SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 > ALL (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
```

You may have meant to use and remove **one** of the `where` in your query:

***Sidenote:*** You can only use a **single** `WHERE` in a query.

```
 where parent_id='0' AND categories_id like '%local%' order by `sort_order` ASC 
 LIMIT 0, 25
```

or use `OR` instead of `AND` depending on the query

```
 where parent_id='0' OR categories_id like '%local%' order by `sort_order` ASC 
 LIMIT 0, 25
```

You may have wanted to check if the search was found inside all the columns, in that case you will need to use the actual column names, seperated by `AND` and/or `OR`, depending on the criteria:

```
where parent_id='0' 
AND categories_id LIKE '%local%' 
AND categories_name LIKE '%local%'

AND parent_id LIKE '%local%' 
AND sort_order LIKE '%local%'

AND date_added LIKE '%local%' 
AND is_active LIKE '%local%'

order by `sort_order` ASC 
 LIMIT 0, 25
```

or:

```
where parent_id='0' 
OR categories_id LIKE '%local%' 
OR categories_name LIKE '%local%'

OR parent_id LIKE '%local%' 
OR sort_order LIKE '%local%'

OR date_added LIKE '%local%' 
OR is_active LIKE '%local%'

order by `sort_order` ASC 
 LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: @obiNullPoiиteяkenobi Thank you. I wanted to make sure I could cover as many bases as I could.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed an issue after WHERE condition.

`where All Fields` should be `WHERE <Field_Name> like '%local%' order by sort_order` ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT categories_id, categories_name, parent_id, sort_order, date_added, is_active FROM ct_testing_menu_title where parent_id='0' AND `All` Fields like '%local%' order by sort_order ASC LIMIT 0, 25
```

you also use OR operator

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two `WHERE` clauses in the same query. If you want to test multiple conditions, you connect them with `AND`.

Second, you can't just say `All Fields`. You need to specify the columns explicitly. So it should be:

```
SELECT categories_id, categories_name, parent_id, sort_order, date_added, is_active 
FROM ct_testing_menu_title 
where parent_id='0' 
AND Field1 like '%local%' 
AND Field2 LIKE '%local%'
AND Field3 LIKE '%local%'
order by `sort_order` ASC 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Replace `Field1`, `Field2`, and so on with the actual names of the columns you want to match.